# ROS2: issues building the composition demo found in ros2/demos

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS2 version dashing on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I am failing to build the ros2 demos found at:

https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/composition

Steps to reproduce:

> 

```
$ mkdir -p ros2_demos_ws/src
$ cd ros2_demos_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/ros2/demos
```

I place `COLCON_IGNORE` in all the folders that I want colcon to ignore (basically all the demos except the "composition" demo).

> 

```
$ cd ros2_demos_ws
$ colcon build --symlink-install
```

Which results in the following output.

```
[0.192s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.catkin:The path 
'home/ros2_example_ws/install/examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client' in the environment variable 
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist
--- stderr: composition                         
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:133 (find_package):
By not providing "Findlaunch_testing_ament_cmake.cmake" in
CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package
configuration file provided by "launch_testing_ament_cmake", but CMake did
not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"launch_testing_ament_cmake" with any of the following names:

   launch_testing_ament_cmakeConfig.cmake
   launch_testing_ament_cmake-config.cmake

 Add the installation prefix of "launch_testing_ament_cmake" to
 CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "launch_testing_ament_cmake_DIR" to a directory
 containing one of the above files.  If "launch_testing_ament_cmake"
 provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
 installed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330417/ros2:-issues-building-the-composition-demo-found-in-ros2/demos/) by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2019-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zmk5](https://answers.ros.org/users/44691/zmk5/) on 2019-08-10**:
How did you install ros2 dashing? The package it is looking for is within the default installation of dashing seen [here](https://index.ros.org/p/launch_testing_ament_cmake/github-ros2-launch/#dashing-overview). Did you source the ros2 installation before running `colcon build --symlink-install`?

EDIT:

Also would you be so kind as to format above so it is more code like for future people who may have this issue?

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2019-08-10**:\

1. I installed following the instructions [Installing ROS2 via Debian Packages](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Install-Debians/)
2. Yes, after installation I set up the environment by running `source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash`.

**Comment by [zmk5](https://answers.ros.org/users/44691/zmk5/) on 2019-08-10**:
Try the following:

```
sudo apt install ros-dashing-launch*
```

Once the packages are installed, source your ros2 installation, and then try and build again.

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2019-08-10**:
The build finished successfully and the composition demo worked. Thanks for the help. Wondering why these were left out?

Running `sudo apt install ros-dashing-launch*` resulted in installing the following packages that weren't installed originally.

```
ros-dashing-launch-testing ros-dashing-launch-testing-ament-cmake ros-dashing-launch-testing-ros
```

Once installed, I sourced the ros2 installation:

```
$ . /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
```

Then ran colcon build:

```
$ colcon build --symlink-install
```

Which resulted in a warning, but build finished successfully.

```
[0.197s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_ros.prefix_path.ament:The path 
'/home/ros2_example_ws/install/examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber' in the environment 
variable AMENT_PREFIX_PATH doesn't exist
```

Then to run the demo:

```
$ . install/setup.bash
$ ros2 launch composition composition_demo.launch.py
```

**Comment by [zmk5](https://answers.ros.org/users/44691/zmk5/) on 2019-08-11**:
Don't worry about the warning. I don't think it will apply to what you needed. The demo started properly, correct? If so, I'll make a formal answer and you can accept it for future users who may have this problem :-)

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2019-08-11**:
Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To solve this issue, install the following packages:

```
sudo apt install ros-dashing-launch*
```

Once the packages are installed, source your ros2 installation, and then try and build again.

---

Originally posted by [zmk5](https://answers.ros.org/users/44691/zmk5/) with karma: 71 on 2019-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4